# Accurev diff pane against Most Recent Version instead of Basis Version

Tags: accurev

In the Accurev stream browser under Outgoing, is it possible to change the Diff pane setting so it compares against Most Recent Version instead of the default Basis Version?

I'm asking because by default the Diff pane seems to compare against the Basis Version. This may be good for promoting, but if I work for a week in my workspace and keep files regulary, then modified files are compared against the basis, not the previous kept version. It makes it hard to see what really changed in my workspace.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

Change the way in which you are diffing files.

Instead of using the "Outgoing" mode diff feature when you select an file.

Right click on the file -> Diff Against -> Choose the type of diff you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Actually, right-clicking is what I wanted to avoid since the Diff pane exists. It is very handy when previewing modified files before keeping or promoting.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `D` is keyboard shortcut for diff most recent version.